# Office 2007 install limit

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, licensing

I reached my install limit due to broken PC's needing to be replaced a few times by the manufacturer.  Can I get my install limit reset somehow?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to contact the Microsoft Activation Centre and explain to them what happened.